# How does MCPhaseGate/MCU1Gate works internally in qiskit?

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, qiskit, gate-synthesis

I was curious about the implementation of [MCPhase](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates/p.py#L216)/[MCU1Gate](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates/u1.py#L233) and how it works without ancilla qubits. I ended up checking the code of the some auxiliary (?) function `_gray_code_chain()` but I couldn't understand much of it.

update: it seems that MCU1Gate is deprecated and MCPhase will substitute it - the code is the same anyway.

Comment: Are you looking for how the gate is implemented with elementary ones?

Comment: Exactly @MartinVesely, I just updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function `_gray_code_chain` is a reference to the [bit-string ordering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code). The application of the algorithm in multi-controlled-gate decomposition is explained in [*Quantum Circuits for General Multiqubit Gates*,
Mottonen, et. al](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0404089v3) and in [*Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*, Nielsen & Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), section 4.5.2 p191.